How can I supply my PWM controller with aux winding in fly-back converter topology?
I am almost done designing a fly-back converter. I can get isolated feedback from secondery side and it works well but I have a problem on the primary side. I have to supply my PWM controller with aux winding on the primary side. I modeled and simulated it in PSIM, but it doesn't work. The IC should be fed at the beginning of operation.
How can I do it?


Typically, bootstrapping is achieved by charging the cap on the controller's supply pin trough a large value resistor straight from the bus voltage.

Just a small comment : you seem to be using the same ground symbol for both primary and secondary sides : if this is indeed the case, then you don't have real isolation


The IC should be feeded at begining of operation. How can I do it?

In order to use the aux winding voltage as the chip supply, the regulator must be operating normally, so the switching must be on. In order to get the switching action started, the chip must be supplied externally.
There are two options here:

Feed the IC directly from the DC input bus through a resistor
Use an external (aka auxiliary) regulator.

The first one is the easiest and the most common method. You can do this by placing a resistor from the DC bus and a capacitor:

The capacitor should be able to supply the chip for the first couple of switching cycles in order to get the switching action and the aux winding voltage.
The startup resistor, Rst, should be low enough to provide the startup current even for the minimum DC input voltage, and large enough to keep the losses minimum (the the resistor will constantly dissipate power because it'll be across the DC bus and the aux supply). Also, the capacitor and the startup resistor will bring a turn-on delay.
A maximum of 150-200 kΩ should be enough.
